# I'm trying to merge two sorted arrays but getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 can't figure out why

Tags: java, sorting, merge

It is going out bounds on the first if statement even after I'm checking the values of j and k before incrementing

```
`int[] Merge(int[]a,int[]b){
int n=a.length+b.length;
int[] sol= new int[n];
int i=0,j=0,k=0;

while(i<n){

if(a[j]<b[k]){

    sol[i]=a[j];

    if(j<a.length)j++;
}
else if(b[k]<a[j]){

        sol[i]=b[k];

        if(k<b.length)k++;

}

i++;

}


return sol;

}`
```

I can't understand where the array is going out of bounds

Comment: keep in mind that `a[a.length]` is already out of bounds. Valid indices are from `0` to `a.length-1`.

Comment: but doesnt `j<a.length` mean that the max index it can have is `a.length-1`?

Comment: No, you still increase `j` in this case which could then become `a.length` which will lead to the error in the next iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: I'm sorry but i cant understand how is `j` increasing after `if(j<a.length) j++` .Can you please elaborate?

Comment: assume `j` is `a.length-1`, the if condition is then true and `j` will be increased to `a.length`.

Comment: wow ok I didnt realize that.Thanks for your help man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the case when either j=a.length-1 or k=b.length-1 then your if condition [`if(j<a.length)j++`; or `if(k<b.length)k++;`]passes  and makes j==a.length to true  or k==b.length to true and the while loop access the array again when it throws ArrayIndexOutofBound exception . Also your code doesn't handle common elements in the array . Please check the correct code below

```
int[] Merge(int[]a,int[]b){
int n=a.length+b.length;
        int[] sol= new int[n];
        int i=0,j=0,k=0;

        while(i<n){
            if(a[j]<=b[k]){ // equality check handles common case

                sol[i++]=a[j++];
                if(j==a.length)
                   break;

            }
            else if(b[k]<a[j]){
                sol[i++]=b[k++];
                if(k==b.length)
                    break ;

            }


        }
        if(j==a.length) {
            while (k != b.length)
                sol[i++]=b[k++];
        }
        if(k==b.length) {
            while (j != a.length)
                sol[i++]=a[j++];
        }
        return sol;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
if(j<a.length)j++;
```

Here when j = a.length - 1 then it will become a.length because of j++.
Now, a[j] will be out of bounds because j  = a.length. a[a.length] is always out bounds. The indexing starts from 0, so last index is a.length - 1.